# $L^2$ norm of self-convolution

Tags: nt.number-theory, fourier-analysis, asymptotics

For $f\in [0,1]^n$ with $\sum_i f_i = 1$, define the self-convolution $g=f*f$ with
$$g_i = \sum_{j,k \mid j+k \equiv i \bmod n} f_j \cdot f_k$$
and define the L2-norm as
$$\|f\| = \sqrt{\sum_i f_i^2}.$$

**My question** is it true that $$\|g\|\le \|f\|^2 \text{?}$$

I arrived here by translating into the frequency domain   where the convolution becomes multiplication as far as I understand. I also tried to get here with some facts about convolutions and Lp norms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_convolution_inequality but I got a much weaker bound.

EDIT: Sorry, my bound is definitely wrong. The L1-norm of $f,g$ is $1$, so the L2-norm will be at least $1/\sqrt{n}$.
**My real question**: what bounds can we give for $||g||$ in terms of $||f||$?

I'd also be interested if someone can point out the problem with my original hypothesis. Here was my thought process:
Let $F$ denote the fourier transform of $f$, and let $\circ$ denote point-wise multiplication. A basic fact of fourier analysis is $F\circ F = f*f$, and also $F,f$ have the same L2-norm.
Now we compute
$$||F\circ F||^2 = \sum_i F_i^4 \le \left(\sum_i F_i^2\right)^2$$
which seems to imply
$$||f*f||\le ||f||^2.$$
Where have I gone wrong?

Also, it seems that maybe stronger bounds can be achieved for prime $n$. If so, please assume that $n$ is prime.

Comment: $$ g_i = \sum_{j,k \mid j+k \equiv 0 \bmod n} f_j \cdot f_k$$ I wonder whether you meant $$ g_i = \sum_{j,k \mid j+k \equiv i \bmod n} f_j \cdot f_k \text{ ?}$$ As it is, the index $i$ appears on the left side and not on the right side.

Comment: @MichaelHardy yes, that's what I meant

Comment: @AlekWestover Are you sure $F,f$ have the same L2-norm? You have to be careful with normalizations in fourier analysis.

Comment: @mathworker21 ... Yes.  The Pontryagin dual of $\mathbb Z_m$ is $\mathbb Z_m$, but the pairing uses counting measure in one and uniform measure in the other.

Answer (score 2):

By Cauchy-Schwarz, $|g_i|\le \sum_{j=1}^n|f_j|^2$ and $\|g\|\le \sqrt n \|f\|^2$. This is sharp because for $f_i=1/n$ for all $1\le i\le n$ we get  the equality.

Comment: This seems true, but very weak if f has large L2 norm say larger than n^{1/4}. Can anything be said in that regime? My intuition is that g should have smaller L2 norm than f and usually much smaller. Are there counter examples?

Comment: Sorry, I understood you wanted a bound  $\|g\|\le c\|f\|^2$, for which $c=\sqrt n$ is trivially optimal. As $\|f\|$ increases, $f$ has to be more and more close to a face of the simplex $\{f: f_i\ge0,\sum_if_i=1\}$, that is, more and more coordinates of $f$ are small.  So I guess it may be useful to  consider the optimization problem $\max_f \|f*f\|$ with an additional  constraint $\text{supp} f=J\subset\{1,\dots,n\}$. Note that the limit case $\|f\|=1$ implies $f=e_i$ for some $i$ and $\|f*f\|=1$.

Comment: Thanks! I'll think about it. I like the supp f constraint